# Dependency injection using ".properties" file

Tags: configuration, dependency-injection, annotations, java-ee-6, cdi

I am using Java EE 6 and need to load configuration from a ".properties" file. Is there a recommended way (best practice) to load the values ​​from the configuration file using dependency injection? I found annotations for this in Spring, but I have not found a "standard" annotation for Java EE.

This guy have developed a solution from scratch:

> http://weblogs.java.net/blog/jjviana/archive/2010/05/18/applicaction-configuration-java-ee-6-using-cdi-simple-example
>
> "I couldn't find a simple example of how to configure your application
>   with CDI by reading configuration attributes from a file..."

But I wonder if there is a more standard way instead of creating a configuration factory...

Answer (score 3):

Configuration annotation

```java
package com.ubiteck.cdi;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import javax.enterprise.util.Nonbinding;
import javax.inject.Qualifier;

@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface InjectedConfiguration {
    /**
     * Bundle key
     * @return a valid bundle key or ""
     */
    @Nonbinding String key() default "";
    /**
     * Is it a mandatory property
     * @return true if mandator
     */
    @Nonbinding boolean mandatory() default false;
    /**
     * Default value if not provided
     * @return default value or ""
     */
    @Nonbinding String defaultValue() default "";
 }
```

The configuration factory could look like :

```java
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.util.MissingResourceException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.InjectionPoint;

public class ConfigurationInjectionManager {
    static final String INVALID_KEY="Invalid key '{0}'";
    static final String MANDATORY_PARAM_MISSING = "No definition found for a mandatory configuration parameter : '{0}'";
    private final String BUNDLE_FILE_NAME = "configuration";
    private final ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_FILE_NAME);

    @Produces
    @InjectedConfiguration
    public String injectConfiguration(InjectionPoint ip) throws IllegalStateException {
        InjectedConfiguration param = ip.getAnnotated().getAnnotation(InjectedConfiguration.class);
        if (param.key() == null || param.key().length() == 0) {
            return param.defaultValue();
        }
        String value;
        try {
            value = bundle.getString(param.key());
            if (value == null || value.trim().length() == 0) {
                if (param.mandatory())
                    throw new IllegalStateException(MessageFormat.format(MANDATORY_PARAM_MISSING, new Object[]{param.key()}));
                else
                    return param.defaultValue();
            }
            return value;            
        } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
            if (param.mandatory()) throw new IllegalStateException(MessageFormat.format(MANDATORY_PARAM_MISSING, new Object[]{param.key()}));
            return MessageFormat.format(INVALID_KEY, new Object[]{param.key()});
        }
    }
```

[Tutorial with explanation and Arquillian test](http://www.java-tutorial.ch/context-and-dependency-injection/property-file-configuration-using-injection-cdi)

Comment: thanks! how can we change programatically the BUNDLE_FILE_NAME here? For example program A a may use "a.properies" and program B "b.properties" but would like to share this code.

Comment: how do you define the file that being injected? and where it reads it from?

Answer (score 1):

Even though it does not exactly cover your question, [this part](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.1.0.Final/en-US/html_single/#resources) of the Weld documentation might be of interest for you.

Having mentioned this - no, there is no standard way to inject arbitrary resources / resource files. I guess it's simply beyond the scope of a spec to standardise such highly custom-dependent requirement (Spring is no specification, they can simply implement whatever they like). However, what CDI provides is a strong (aka typesafe) mechanism to inject configuration-holding beans on one side, and a flexible producer mechanism to read and create such beans on the other side. Definitely this is the recommended way you were asking about.

The approach you are linking to is certainly a pretty good one - even though it might me too much for your needs, depending on the kind of properties you are planning to inject.

A very CDI-ish way of continuing would be to develop a CDI extension (that would nicely encapsulate all required classes) and deploy it independently with your projects. Of course you can also contribute to the [CDI-extension catalog](http://groups.diigo.com/group/cdi-extensions) or even [Apache Deltaspike](https://cwiki.apache.org/DeltaSpike/).

Comment: "Spring is no specification, they can simply implement whatever they like" - yes, but specifications don't come from heaven. Someone has written it, just like someone has written Spring.

Answer (score 1):

The only "standard" way of doing this would be to use a qualifier with a nonbinding annotation member, and make sure all of your injections are dependent scoped. Then in your producer you can get a hold of the InjectionPoint and get the key off the qualifier in the injection point. You'd want something like this:

```java
@Qualifier
public @interface Property {
    @Nonbinding String value default "";
}

...
@Inject @Property("myKey") String myKey;


...
@Produces @Property public String getPropertyByKey(InjectionPoint ip) {
    Set<Annotation> qualifiers = ip.getQualifiers

    // Loop through qualifers looking for Property.class save that off
    return ResourceBundle.getBundle(...).getString(property.key);
}
```

There are obviously some enhancements you can do to that code, but it should be enough to get you started down the right track.

Answer (score 1):

See @ConfigProperty of Apache DeltaSpike